# Forwarding references, ref qualifiers and template member functions

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, member-functions, forwarding-reference

Take the following member function:

```
struct T {
    template <typename X> void f(X&& x) { /* ... */ }
};
```

In this case, `x` is a forwarding reference because `&&` is used for the function parameters inside of a template. This is as expected.

Now take this function:

```
struct T {
    template <typename X> void f(X&& x) && { /* ... */ }
};
```

I would expect that `this` would be treated in a similar manner; as a forwarding reference. Therefore, I would expect the following program to compile and run just fine:

```
#include <iostream>

struct T {
    template <typename X>
    bool operator<(X&& rhs) && {
        std::cout << "&&" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    T t;
    std::cout << (t < T()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But using GCC 4.8.4 and 6.0.1, it does not. Instead, I get the following:

```
rvalue.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
rvalue.cpp:13:25: error: passing ‘T’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool T::operator<(X&&) && [with X = T]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 std::cout << (t < T()) << std::endl;
```

It would appear that `this` is not made a forwarding reference.
Is this correct or an error? Should `this` be treated as a forwarding reference? What part of the standard specifies this?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg just tried it with 6.0.1, same result. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two `&&`s` here are treated differently:

```
struct T {
    template <typename X> void f(X&& x) && { /* ... */ }
};
```

You are correct in that `x` is a forwarding reference. But the `&&` on the right is a qualification on the object instance. In this case, `f()` can only be invoked if the object instance is an rvalue (perhaps adding to the confusion is that the first `&&` takes `x` as a forwarding reference but the second `&&` takes the implicit object parameter as an rvalue reference). That is:

```
T().f(4); // ok

T t;
t.f(4); // error
```

This works the same way as `const` qualification does:

```
struct X { void f(); };
const X cx;
cx.f(); // error
```

Comment: So the template doesn't affect how the `&&` is applied to `this`?

Comment: @OMGtechy These are entirely separate concepts. You can't template the qualification of a function - if you want lvalue and rvalue overloads you need to have `&`- and `&&`-qualified functions, separately.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a place in the standard where this distinction is specified?

Comment: @OMGtechy cv-qualifiers and ref-qualifiers control the type of the implicit `this` parameter - which is spelled out in [\[over.match.funcs\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#4).

Answer (score 2):

The reference qualifier at the end of the function states that `operator<` should only be called when the LHS is a temporary.  Remember a operator can be called like any other member function so what you have is

```
t.operator<(T())
```

and `t` is not a temporary.

If we change your example to

```
std::cout << (T() < t) << std::endl;
```

Then it works just fine as the object you are calling the `operator<` on is a temporary object.

Comment: I understand this, what I'm asking is why `this` isn't made a forwarding reference like the argument is.

Comment: @OMGtechy Because the compiler isn't just going to convert your object into a rvalue.  If it did then reference qualification would be useless.  You said the function should only be called on a rvalue.  When you break that and call it on a object that is an lvalue you get a compiler error.

Comment: @OMGtechy: First of all, there is a difference between *forwarding-reference* and *rvalue-reference* . Second, inside a member function, `this` is **neither** a forwarding-reference, **nor** a rvalue-reference, even inside functions which can be invoked only on rvalue, in which case `this`, though still an lvalue itself, binds to *rvalue* expression.

Comment: @Nawaz I know the distinction, I was expecting `this` to be a forwarding reference (incorrectly it seems) :)

Comment: @OMGtechy: If you know then you must be knowing the term *forwarding-reference* is relevant only in the context of *function template* parameter  of the form of `T&&`. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense; it doesn't have any relevant anywhere else, not even in class template parameter. It *has to be* function template first of all, then the parameter *must be* of the form of `T&&`.

Comment: or `auto&&` which really is just `T&&`.

Answer (score 0):

The member `operator<() &&` can be called on *rvalue* only, so the following:

```
t < T()
```

is not going to work, because `t` is not *rvalue* — it is *lvalue*.

The following should work:

```
std::move(t) < T()
```

and this too:

```
T{} < T{}
```

Note that I've used `{}` as I'm more comfortable with them and they work without much surprise.